# is there any profit of using E-commerce PHP Frameworks?

Tags: php, frameworks

I want to know from a technical view if there is any profit of using E-commerce PHP 
frameworks instead of hard coding every single detail in the website.

I see everybuddy talk about using those but is there any real profit (not just because it is more easy it should be done no ?) for now i have a project of a commercial site and i have build-ed from scratch the search engine and the navigation system and some other few things any help please (NO VOTE DOwn PLEASE if this is a bad question one comment and it will vanish).

Comment: As it could potentially save a lot of time - yes, sometimes it does worth to use some 3rd party code

Comment: This question is off topic and subjective. Some variation of it might be appropriate at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the good things in E-commerce PHP frameworks is that they are well documented, easy to install, full functionality, less to work as updates and upgrades most of the time.

if you want to build one from scrach you should take a note that it could last several months (depends on the size of the project) and you will never know what bugs you have ... as the only person who knows the backend is you.

there is a profit ... since a new one from scrach takes a lot of time and testing ... and time=money ...

Why don't you test, most of them give out demos and there are a lot of them that are open source ...

Comment: Examples PLease and if you can order them by popularity

Comment: search google, I don't have a pupularity list as I dont use them anymore, but a good list you can find on http://blog.webdistortion.com/2008/05/03/9-kick-ass-open-source-e-commerce-platforms-reviewed/

Comment: Wait !!! you suggested you dont use them ? (e-commerce frameworks)
so why you telling me that there is a profit of using them ??

Comment: I just told you my opinion, I said I don't use them .. I never said I didn't use them.

Answer (score 1):

e-commerce is more of a pain in the ass than you think at first. you have to make a large order form and build validation and sanitation scripts and spend a lot of time making the layout not look like scrap, encryption and SSL integration and then after all that it needs an admin with way too much to account for. i've done this and ... never again.